# What is the meaning of "that" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, relative-pronouns

What is the meaning of "that" in the following sentence,

> "I am about to reveal something to you that has taken me months to
>   work up the nerve to confess"

?

Does that mean "To revel something to you" ?

Does it mean "I am about to reveal something to you. To reveal something to you has taken me months to work up the nerve to confess " ?

If so, I would be grateful if you could introduce some examples that are used in this way.

Comment: "That" refers to "something", that is, "the information that I'm going to reveal to you".

Comment: "That" is anaphoric to "something". We understand that "something has taken me months to ..., and I'm about to reveal it to you".

Comment: If so, does "I am about to reveal something to you that has taken me months to work up the nerve to confess" mean " I am about to reveal to you something that has taken me months. and I work up the nerve to confess something" ?

Comment: 'Something has taken me months to work up the nerve to confess, and I am about to reveal that "something" to you'.

Comment: BillJ // If so, does "'Something has taken me months to work up the nerve to confess, and I am about to reveal that "something" to you'." mean "Something has taken me months and I work up the nerve to confess something, and I am about to reveal that something to you" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I am about to reveal something to you.  The thing I am about to reveal to you has taken me months to work up the nerve to confess"

... is how I would rephrase it.

---

> 4. That as a Relative Pronoun
>
> That is also used as a relative pronoun: I bought the book that is
>   required for this course.  The Longman Grammar found that that as a
>   relative pronoun is more common in academic writing and newspaper
>   writing than in conversation.  Indeed, conversation tends to have more
>   of those sentences where the relative pronoun is dropped: I bought the
>   book required for this course.

Source: *[The Many Uses of That](http://www2.gsu.edu/~eslhpb/grammar/lecture_13/that.html)*